# Getting redirected to the details Page on Click

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

Am making a simple react js app that displays a list of companies from a Node js / express server in a table.

Each row when clicked shows a modal with some of the details about that company , the modal has two buttons one for closing and the other for seeing the full details of the company.

Am trying to redirect the user to an other page with the full details of the company when the full details button is clicked.

I know i can pass the id as props and then use axios to fetch the company details using that id from the endpoint ("localhost:5000/companies/id"),
But the redirecting to the new page part am not familiar with so i appreciate any help in regards of this or a better way to implement this functionality.

Here is the code i used to show case the table :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import BootStrapTable from "react-bootstrap-table-next"
import paginationFactory from 'react-bootstrap-table2-paginator';
import {Modal , Button} from "react-bootstrap"

export default function DataTable (){
    const [companies,setCompanies] = useState([]);
    const [modalInfo,setModalInfo] = useState([]);
    const [showModal,setShowModal] = useState(false);
    const [show ,setShow] = useState(false);
    const handleCLose = () => setShow(false)
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true)
    const getCompaniesData = async () =>{
        try{
            const data = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/companies")
            setCompanies(data.data)
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        getCompaniesData();
    },[])
    const columns = [
        {dataField:"id",text:"id"},
        {dataField:"name",text:"name"},
     
    ]
    const rowEvents = {
        onClick : (e,row)=>{
            console.log(row)
            setModalInfo(row)
            toggleTrueFalse()
            
        }
    }
    const toggleTrueFalse = () =>{
        setShowModal(handleShow);
    }
    const ModalContent = () =>{
     return (   <Modal show={show} onHide={handleCLose}>
<Modal.Header closeButton>
    <Modal.Title>
        {modalInfo.name}
    </Modal.Title>
</Modal.Header>
<Modal.Body>
<h1 >Company Details :</h1>
<ul>
     <ol>source_id : {modalInfo.source_id}</ol>
     <ol>source_name : {modalInfo.source_name}</ol>
     <ol>name : {modalInfo.name}</ol>
     <ol>website : {modalInfo.website}</ol>
     <ol>email : {modalInfo.email}</ol>
     <ol>phone : {modalInfo.phone}</ol>
     <ol>postal_code : {modalInfo.postal_code}</ol>
     <ol>city : {modalInfo.city}</ol>
     <ol>country : {modalInfo.country}</ol>
</ul>
</Modal.Body>
<Modal.Footer>
<Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleCLose}>Full Details</Button>
    <Button className="btn btn-danger" variant="secondary" onClick={handleCLose}>Close</Button>
</Modal.Footer>
        </Modal> )
    }
    return (
        <div>
        <h1 className="text-center">Share-work Data Table</h1>
        <BootStrapTable
        keyField="id"
        data={companies}
        columns={columns}
        pagination={paginationFactory()}
        rowEvents = {rowEvents}
        />
        {show ? <ModalContent/> : null}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use react-router-dom history hooks:

First import useHistory from react-router-dom

```
const history = useHistory();
```

then you can replacce with a function onClick in your Button:

```
history.push('yourpath', {details:detail})
```

either history.replace should work:

```
history.replace('yourpath', {details:detail})
```

In the following page in your case will be details page you can access your details with the hook useLocation from react-router-dom:

First import useLocation from react-router-dom

```
location = useLocation();
```

to access it:

```
location.state.details
```

I hope this work for you